# SSH tunnel on remote Windows loads infinitely

Tags: remote-desktop, ssh-tunnel

I have the following setup: I need to maintain a web application on a remote Linux server. When I work from my company, I connect there via PuTTY with an SSH tunnel for the port `localhost:8080` as 8002. So far, this has always worked.

Now I'm in the home office. Because the Linux server only allows connections via our company public IP, I log in there via VPN and use a remote desktop connection to a virtual machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard in our company. There, I have PuTTY and Firefox to work. I can connect to the Linux server with PuTTY, but in Firefox (on the remote desktop, too), when I call the forwarded port, it hangs infinitely loading. (Also, no error "connection unavailable". The same is true for Internet Explorer.) On the Linux shell, I get HTML output immediately with `wget`, so it is not that the service is not responding. What could that be?

[image: Screenshot]

Even stranger: My colleague uses the same setup (we even diff´ed the PuTTY settings from the registry) and he encounters no comparable issues.

Any idea what can cause this or how to debug this?

Comment: Do you know that `localhost` is the address of the computer where firefox opened?

Comment: Of course, and that should be correct. Firefox runs on the terminal to which I connected. The putty also runs on the terminal and should forward the port to the Linux server. It seems to be doing something, otherwise I would get a timeout, but that doesn't happen.